# multiple hidden forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a php mysql application. On a detail view page, I am looking at rows of data. I want to use jquery form plugin to do form submitting. What I am not sure of is that i need to have a hidden form for every record in case they want to update a certain bit of data. Im not sure how i should create the form. Should the form be hidden and contain an unique id of each hidden form? Should i create the form using an ajax request to create the form by passing the same parameters that i would have used in create the forms once at page load? Should i create the form values on the fly?

What is a good practice for having hidden forms or dynamic forms using jquery form plugin. This could also be a terribly worded question.

Comment: Why would you need hidden inputs?

Comment: I don't think you want to use the form plugin, this is designed for a simple form, sounds like you're doing something more complex. You can process the data fields that you need to update in jQuery and then send them to the server using [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: hidden unless i need to submit a form for that customer. if every row was a different customer, and i wanted to update the 3rd customer, if i havnt created a hidden form for that customer, where would i create the form for the update

Comment: on stack overflow, the comment section im using that you read this from. the form appears after you click comment. Where is this form before that link is clicked that shows this comment form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AJAX to post forms, you don't even need a form on the page. You just need to tell your AJAX post code which fields you want to use, serialize them and then post to the server.

You can use class names to signify which fields belong to which "virtual form" to make it easy to collect your form data for each POST type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal of benefit to the concept of model binding. If you have many fields, hiddens, etc. that rely on the input of other fields, perhaps a library like Knockout would help. It integrates very nicely with jQuery. http://knockoutjs.com/